# Lógica. Empresa com 2 estoques

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela Mysql:

```
`estoque_itensconsumo` (
`cod_itensconsumo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`unidade_mendida` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`estoque_atual` INT NULL,
`quant_minima` INT NULL,
`valor_custo` FLOAT(9,2) NULL,
`registrar_cliente` INT NULL,
`ativo` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cod_itensconsumo`))
```

A empresa tem duas filiais cadastradas em outra tabela. Existe a possibilidade de transferir produtos de uma filial para a outra. Não encontrei uma forma eficiente de separar os itens que estão em uma filial e em outra.

Exemplo: Tenho 450 roteadores Link One modelo XXXXXX-XXX onde 350 estão não filial A e outros 100 na filial B. Como eu poderia distribuir esses valores na mesma tabela, ou eu teria de ter duas tabelas(uma para cada filial) e cadastrar o roteador do exemplo nas duas?

Comment: Pq vc nao cria uma coluna unidade e cria um identificador para cada caso? Nesse exemplo, vc teria 2 linhas com o mesmo item mas em locais diferentes....Claro, suas rotinas de baixa de estoque, selects teriam que considerar esse fator...

Comment: Pensei nisso, inclusive tenho uma tabela 'unidades' onde cadastrei as filiais e até poderia usar como (FK), mas pensei na situação em que uma terceira filial entrasse na história me fazendo assim alterar a estrutura da tabela.

Comment: Como o @Diego disse você precisa adicionar filial em suas tabelas e manter os dados separados. Se for criada uma nova filial você não precisa alterar a estrutura das tabelas, você simplesmente adiciona uma nova linha ao estoque, caso esse material existe também naquela filial.